# Why do I get a password box when I go to Tools > References when editing my Excel VBA App?

Tags: excel, vba, passwords

When editing an Excel VBA app, I go to Tools > References and a box asking for a password opens up, but I don't recall ever setting a password for the app.  How can I either get around the password box or find out what the password for the app is?  I have no problem editing the app, so it doesn't seem like the app is password protected.